# System of Differential Equations discrepancy

Tags: differential-equations, matrix, system

Using the following code in Mathematica:

```
{X, Y} = {x, y} /. 
    DSolve[{x'[t] == -1/10 x[t] + 3/40 y[t], 
      y'[t] == 1/10 x[t] - 1/5 y[t]}, {x, y}, t] // FullSimplify // 
  First; {X[t], Y[t]} // Expand
```

I get the following solution:

```
{1/4 E^(-t/4) C[1] + 3/4 E^(-t/20) C[1] - 3/8 E^(-t/4) C[2] + 
  3/8 E^(-t/20) C[2], -(1/2) E^(-t/4) C[1] + 1/2 E^(-t/20) C[1] + 
  3/4 E^(-t/4) C[2] + 1/4 E^(-t/20) C[2]}
```

But if I do it by hand, I get:
$
    \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=c_1 e^{-\dfrac{t}{4}} \begin{bmatrix}-1\\2\end{bmatrix}+c_2 e^{-\dfrac{t}{20}} \begin{bmatrix}3\\2\end{bmatrix}
$

So,
$
x(t)=-c_1e^{-\dfrac{t}{4}}+3c_2e^{-\dfrac{t}{20}} \text{ and } y(t)=2c_1e^{-\dfrac{t}{4}}+2c_2e^{-\dfrac{t}{20}}
$

Why is there a discrepancy? How do I simplify Mathematica answer to mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sol = DSolve[
  {x'[t] == -1/10 x[t] + 3/40 y[t],
   y'[t] == 1/10 x[t] - 1/5 y[t]
   }, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
```

\begin{align*}
x(t) =& \frac{1}{4} c_1 e^{-t/4} \left(3 e^{t/5}+1\right)+\frac{3}{8} c_2 e^{-t/4} \left(e^{t/5}-1\right)\\
y(t) =&
   \frac{1}{2} c_1 e^{-t/4} \left(e^{t/5}-1\right)+\frac{1}{4} c_2 e^{-t/4} \left(e^{t/5}+3\right)
\end{align*}

is the same as your solution.

Proof:

\begin{align*}
x\left(  t\right)    & =\frac{1}{4}e^{-\frac{t}{4}}\left(  1+3e^{\frac{t}{5}
}\right)  c_{1}+\frac{3}{8}e^{-\frac{t}{4}}\left(  -1+e^{\frac{t}{5}}\right)
c_{2}\\
y\left(  t\right)    & =\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{t}{4}}\left(  -1+e^{\frac{t}{5}
}\right)  c_{1}+\frac{1}{4}e^{-\frac{t}{4}}\left(  3+e^{\frac{t}{5}}\right)
c_{2}
\end{align*}
Hence
\begin{align*}
x\left(  t\right)    & =\frac{1}{4}\left(  e^{-\frac{t}{4}}+3e^{\frac{-t}{20}
}\right)  c_{1}+\frac{3}{8}\left(  -e^{-\frac{t}{4}}+e^{\frac{-t}{20}}\right)
c_{2}\\
y\left(  t\right)    & =\frac{1}{2}\left(  -e^{-\frac{t}{4}}+e^{\frac{-t}{20}
}\right)  c_{1}+\frac{1}{4}\left(  3e^{-\frac{t}{4}}+e^{\frac{-t}{20}}\right)
c_{2}
\end{align*}
Or
\begin{align*}
x\left(  t\right)    & =e^{-\frac{t}{4}}\left(  \frac{1}{4}c_{1}-\frac{3}
{8}c_{2}\right)  +e^{\frac{-t}{20}}\left(  \frac{3}{4}c_{1}+\frac{3}{8}
c_{2}\right)  \\
y\left(  t\right)    & =e^{-\frac{t}{4}}\left(  -\frac{1}{2}c_{1}+\frac{3}
{4}c_{2}\right)  +e^{\frac{-t}{20}}\left(  \frac{1}{2}c_{1}+\frac{1}{4}
c_{2}\right)
\end{align*}
Let $\frac{1}{4}c_{1}-\frac{3}{8}c_{2}=-A$ and let $\frac{3}{4}c_{1}+\frac
{3}{8}c_{2}=3B$ where $A,B$ are new constants. Hence $-\frac{1}{2}c_{1}
+\frac{3}{4}c_{2}=2A$ and $\frac{1}{4}c_{1}+\frac{1}{8}c_{2}=B$ or $\frac
{1}{2}c_{1}+\frac{1}{4}c_{2}=2B$ Hence the above becomes
\begin{align*}
x\left(  t\right)    & =-Ae^{-\frac{t}{4}}+3Be^{\frac{-t}{20}}\\
y\left(  t\right)    & =2Ae^{-\frac{t}{4}}+2Be^{\frac{-t}{20}}
\end{align*}
But $A,B$ are constants. We can call them anything we want. Let $A=c_{1}$
and $B=c_{2}$. The above becomes
\begin{align*}
x\left(  t\right)    & =-c_{1}e^{-\frac{t}{4}}+3c_{2}e^{\frac{-t}{20}}\\
y\left(  t\right)    & =2c_{1}e^{-\frac{t}{4}}+2c_{2}e^{\frac{-t}{20}}
\end{align*}

Which is your solution

Comment: Thanks! Nasser. Appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

How to find the transformation from Mathematica's solution to the OP's soluytion:

```
mmaSol =  (* DSolve[]'s solution *)
   {1/4 E^(-t/4) C[1] + 3/4 E^(-t/20) C[1] - 
    3/8 E^(-t/4) C[2] + 3/8 E^(-t/20) C[2], -(1/2) E^(-t/4) C[1] + 
    1/2 E^(-t/20) C[1] + 3/4 E^(-t/4) C[2] + 1/4 E^(-t/20) C[2]};
opSol =  (* OP's solution *)
  {-C[3] E^(-t/4) + 3 C[4] E^(-t/20), 
   2 C[3] E^(-t/4) + 2 C[4] E^(-t/20)};

mma2op = First@Solve[mmaSol == opSol, {C[1], C[2]}]
(*  {C[1] -> -C[3] + 3 C[4], C[2] -> 2 (C[3] + C[4])}  *)
```

The transformation is applied with `/.` (`ReplaceAll`):

```
mmaSol /. mma2op
```

Check:

```
(mmaSol /. mma2op) == opSol // Simplify
(*  True  *)
```